# Wp_query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Could you help me with wp_query?
I need to show the first 5 posts in one block and next 5-10 posts in the second block
All post from one category
offset=5 didn't help

```
<section class="section_ad">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<h2>бъявления</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-12 block_ad">
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<ul class="ul_ad ul_brd">

<?php $cat = new WP_query(); $cat->query('orderby=id&showposts=5&cat=6'); ?>
<?php while ($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<span><?php the_time('j F'); ?></span>
<a class="link_ad" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<ul class="ul_ad">
<?php $cat = WP_query('offset=5'); $cat->query('orderby=id&showposts=5&cat=6'); ?>
<?php while ($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<span><?php the_time('j F'); ?></span>
<a class="link_ad" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this. I have changed the WP_query to WP_Query and pass the offset argument with other arguments.

```
<section class="section_ad">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<h2>бъявления</h2>
</div>
<div class="col-12 block_ad">
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<ul class="ul_ad ul_brd">

<?php $cat = new WP_Query(); $cat->query('orderby=id&showposts=5&cat=6'); ?>
<?php while ($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<span><?php the_time('j F'); ?></span>
<a class="link_ad" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<ul class="ul_ad">
<?php $cat = new WP_Query(); $cat->query('orderby=id&showposts=5&cat=6&offset=5'); ?>
<?php while ($cat->have_posts()) : $cat->the_post(); ?>
<li>
<span><?php the_time('j F'); ?></span>
<a class="link_ad" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</section>
```